# php mysql search with special character

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table in mysql DB which contains special character like Ø,Æ,etc. I cannot find these fields when i run a search with php. but when i run the same sql in phpmyadmin, i get results.
this is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clientinfo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `adresse` varchar(160) NOT NULL,
  `gatenavn` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `husnr` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `bokstav` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `postnr` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `poststed` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=398 ;
```

This is a sample query:

```
SELECT * FROM clientinfo WHERE gatenavn = 'EKRAVEIEN' AND husnr = '1' AND postnr = '2010' AND poststed = 'STRØMMEN'
```

when i run this query in phpmyadmin, i get result; but don't get when i run with php. I am using mysqli. need some help.

Comment: Check the charset of the html document, and set it to utf8;
USe `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` in your httpd.conf
Set `default_charset = "utf-8";` in your php.ini file

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 3):

Tell your connection instance, to deliver UTF-8, before making queries. In MySqli you can call the function `set_charset()`, afterwards the connection object will deliver UTF-8.

Calling this function makes you independent of the database configuration, if necessary the connection will convert the returned data. Of course it is fastest if no conversion is necessary, so adjusting the configuration is a good thing too.

```
// tells the mysqli connection to deliver UTF-8 encoded strings.
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPassword, $dbName);
$db->set_charset('utf8');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting :

`SET NAMES utf8;`

before your query in the same mysql session

Comment: actually it works when i use normal php mysql_query functions. but i am using mysqli. for this i have tried: $mysqli->set_charset('utf8'); but does not work.

Comment: @Imrul.H - Did you also call `set_charset('utf-8')` before you inserted data to the database? If you query the data with UTF-8 which was inserted in another encoding, it will not work of course. Try to add a new row and make a query afterwards.

Comment: Hi again, when i am using set_charset('utf-8') before insert, then "STRØMMEN" inserts as "STR". i am using Collation as "utf8_general_ci" in mysql database.

Comment: so the problem is at insert not select?

Comment: @Imrul.H - The collation doesn't matter in this case, it is only used for ordering. If the string is not inserted correctly, i suspect, that your PHP page is not correctly encoded in UTF-8. Maybe you want to have a look at my small [article](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#utf8), it shows the important points for working with UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your MySQL configuration file, set these settings to `my.cfg`:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

Answer (score -1):

Try  using [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.htmlspecialchars.php) php function.

```
string htmlspecialchars ( string $string , int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401
                         , string $encoding = 'UTF-8' , bool $double_encode = true)
```

You can change the `encoding` info of your string. Eg `KOI8-R` for Russian symbols

Comment: what good would that do? If `Ø` is what's literally in the database, then searching for `&Oring;` is still not going to find anything.

Comment: Sorry, I thought about store et search using htmlspecialchars. Forget it if others solution (set charset) work.

Answer (score -1):

This could be a issue with your php.ini file, your Apache Webserver, or charset of your HTML Document or your MySQL

Couple of things to to:

Always ensure that your `charset` is set to `utf8` in your html meta tags

Set

```
default_charset = "utf-8";
```

in your php.ini file

And  add

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

to your httpd.conf if you are outputting unicode chars